# How to track what setup.exe has installed

Tags: setup, tracking

1. Is there a way to track what the setup file has installed? Everything - Registry, files.
2. Is there a way to track down what kind of files software creates? Cookies & all other files it creates on the system.

Comment: Yes, random installer, not recovering my own.

Answer (score 2):

*ahem ahem*

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645):

> Process Monitor is an advanced
>   monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and
>   process/thread activity. It combines
>   the features of two legacy
>   Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and
>   Regmon, and adds an extensive list of
>   enhancements including rich and
>   non-destructive filtering,
>   comprehensive event properties such
>   session IDs and user names, reliable
>   process information, full thread
>   stacks with integrated symbol support
>   for each operation, simultaneous
>   logging to a file, and much more. Its
>   uniquely powerful features will make
>   Process Monitor a core utility in your
>   system troubleshooting and malware
>   hunting toolkit.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You could run the installation in a sandbox (like [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)) and see what it has changed.  Then you can either reinstall in the live OS or break the application out of the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's not guaranteed to work, but I have done this before by using a fresh installation of Wine on a Linux machine. Run the installer using Wine and then check out what's happened under `~/.wine/`. The registry changes and files installed should mirror exactly what happens on a Windows machine.

Comment: I do not have any work experience with Linux or Wine. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

What OS?

[InCtrl5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InCtrl5).  You should be able to find it around on various "archive" websites.

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) (the Pro, shareware version) has "Real-Time monitoring of system changes - during install of programs".

[SpyMe Tools](http://www.lcibrossolutions.com/spyme_tools.htm)

[Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/total-uninstall.php)

[PRIMO](http://members.tripod.com/~randy_hall/download.htm)

(I'm only familiar with InCtrl5.)