# Tracing activities during installations

Tags: windows-7, installation, setup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to track what setup.exe has installed](https://superuser.com/questions/290158/how-to-track-what-setup-exe-has-installed)

Is there any way to capture what files are modified or copied during an installation/setup process?

In many cases, I need to redo this process when the Windows HDD is gone, and just copying the application files will not work sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practise, this does not always work, so you really need to keep the original installation files.

To give a very trivial example, suppose you install a program which requires some third party component (for example Microsoft' Visual C++ Runtime). You then install another program which also requires this component. When the second install runs, it detects that this component already exists on the machine it will skip these files and hence your capture routine will not realise this is needed.

So, if you re-format your machine and try to use the second program by copying all the files in your capture log, it will not work because it did not know that it also requires this component.